# Edit TileJSON inside MBTiles files

Tags: mapbox, json, vector-tiles, mbtiles

I want to upload a tileset (I created with tippecanoe) to mapbox. I receive the error:

```
Metadata exceeds limit of 60kb
```

Here: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/uploads/ they suggest to

> Remove extra or unneeded content from the TileJSON file (inside the MBTiles file).

However, I do not really know how to edit this Json as this is basically an sql-database isn't it. Any ideas?:)

Comment: Probably it is easier and faster to make a new tileset with less attributes.

Comment: I cant have less attributes. Its already only the geometry

Comment: All right, and the error is actually about too long metadata-json. You should be able to see what it is with any SQLite tool by following this https://ckochis.com/create-custom-vector-tiles but I do not know how to make it shorter. Because Tippecanoe wrote is I suppose it can be also be configured to write less.